# MTP USB Device installed successfully: is this a virus?

Tags: windows, usb, virus, mtp

I had my flash drive in, so it is believable that some driver was installed automatically, but I have plugged it in previously and never had this happen.  I just got this laptop a few weeks ago; it's a Dell Inspiron 15R running windows 7.  Just a few minutes ago, a popup said that "MPD USB Device installed successfully".  It is currently "searching preconfigured driver folders".  It looked like spyware, but after a whole-computer and anti-rootkit scan, nothing came up.  AVG has failed before; can I get a second opinion on whether or not this is a virus?

Comment: I suggest download and run Malwarebytes: http://www.malwarebytes.org/ It's free and very good.

Comment: The driver is installed each time you plug the drive in a port that has never been used with this drive. This my observation though, not the 'authoritative' answer

Comment: Did the pop up show when you connected any usb device or did it do it randomly?

Comment: No.  I've used the port about 25 times before, and it was at least 15 minutes after I plugged it it.